# How to prevent ssesion from expiring in apex?

Tags: javascript, session, oracle-apex, session-cookies, apex

how can something be done that does not expire the session in oracle apex?
best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the changes in the Administration Workspace so the **INTERNAL** Workspace.

When logged in in your INTERNAL workspace :

1. Manage Instance

[image]

2. Security

[image]

3. Under Session Timeout, you can set the desired number
   [image]

I think that putting 0 on the first makes your session never expiring, you can check it by yourselves by lookgin at the help text, or checking the documentation

---

These steps can also be done under the Shared Component menu on your applications.

**1. Shared Components > Security > Security Attributes > Session Management**

[image]

Comment: thanks,but maximum session idle time cant be larger than 999999.

Answer (score 2):

You could try calling these with very large values:

[APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_LIFETIME_SECONDS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/aeapi/SET_SESSION_LIFETIME_SECONDS-Procedure.html)

[APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_MAX_IDLE_SECONDS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/aeapi/SET_SESSION_MAX_IDLE_SECONDS-Procedure.html)

Comment: thanks,but maximum session idle time cant be larger than 999999

Comment: do you have any idea?

Comment: 999999 seconds is ~11 days.  So is your requirement that the user can log in today, go away, then come back e.g. in 1 years time and they are still logged in?

Comment: yes,Exactly I want the user to stay logged in for a long time

Comment: I don't know a way.  You can make the session lifetime indefinite, but as far as I'm aware you can't make max idle time indefinite, so the session will time out at some point.